# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 using Swagger API:

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am having this error in my Xcode project....So basically what I am doing is creating a static library that uses a Swagger Api that I have installed using CocoaPods. I am able to import the header files and use the header files in the library, but when I put the static library in another Xcode project I receive this error where It says _OBJC_CLASS_$_SWG....", referenced from: objc-class-ref in Sendable.o.... which is basically the class where I am using the Swagger header files.....

Things I have attempted:
1: Delete Derived Data folder, cleaned and rebuilt
2: made sure POD, library, and project using library have the same architectures as well as 
3: made sure architecture build active is set to NO for all
4: made sure $(inherited) is in both library and project using library
5: installed pod file again in library

Things I noticed:
1: the library itself does not have POD in the header search path
2: I get the following warnings but ignored them
3: using Pod update gives me error saying GitHub is offline make sure you have internet connection, only removing and installing seem to work successfully.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are building the library for a single architecture - you are building it either for a `Generic iOS Device`, or some speciffic iOS device. Either way, you will not be able to use the library on a simulator (x86_64 architecture). Vice versa, if you build the library for a simulator, you will not be able to use it on a device.

If you want to use the same build on both devices and simulator, you need to create an universal library using a tool called `lipo`, either manually or by Build Phase script. Check out [this article](https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2016/12/22/how-to-create-universal-static-library-ios/). Short summary:

1. Add an `Aggregate` target to your library project
2. Add a `Run Script` Build Phase
3. Paste this script into it:

```
    # define output folder environment variable
    UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

    # Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
    xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
    xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

    # make sure the output directory exists
    mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

    # Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo
    lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"

    echo "Universal library can be found here:"
    echo ${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a

    # Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
    cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

Build your Aggregate target and an universal library will be built

Comment: Okay, attempted this, it created a new universal .a file and I added to the  sample project. Still getting the same error, but What I did notice that the error does vary depending on whether I use a simulator or real device...X_86 error on simulator, arm64 on device